# unlink original file instead of symbolic link. What to do?

Tags: deleted-files

I had a file with symbolic link

link -> original_file

original_file

I mistakenly ran unlink command with original_file

Now the original file is missing and the symbolic link is broken. What to do? How to recover the original file?

Comment: original_file can be, of course, recover from a backup.

Comment: So that means that file has been removed just like rm do? I thought unlink should only remove sym links

Comment: @RohailAbbas Uh? I wonder why you thought that. `unlink` removes anything except directories and has always done so.

Comment: @Gilles Im new to `linux`. Thanks @mazs for the hard-link - inode concept :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the man page specifies, the `unlink` command will remove a specified file :

```
UNLINK(1)

NAME
   unlink - call the unlink function to remove the specified file
```

Unlink will remove hard-links and symbolic-links as well.
As a file in Linux is a hard-link to an inode, if a regular file is specified as a parameter, this hard-link will be removed, and if the file is the last hard-link to the inode of the file, then the file is kindof erased.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the file system you use, you may still be able to recover the deleted file. There are plenty of tools for `ext2`, and several tools for more complex `ext3` and `ext4`. [For example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/file_recovery), you could try

```
extundelete /dev/sdaX --restore-directory someDirectory
```

This will restore all files found on the partition. If you happen to know the exact inode your file was linked to, you can restore just that file.